# "The term 'Get-MailboxFolderStatistics' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: powershell

I do not know what is happening here, and I need your help!  I contacted my Exchange team, and they verified i have access.
I ran the following commands:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet
Install-Module PowershellGet -Force
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline
```

But I keep getting the following error message:
**"The term 'Get-MailboxFolderStatistics' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"**

I used Powershell and Visual Studio Code with PS on it, still the same...

Comment: you tried <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxfolderstatistics?view=exchange-ps> Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics ?

Comment: I tried using Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics": but i get the following now: "Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics : An error occurred while processing this request"

Comment: Can you run other similar commands? What PS are you using? @Miguel

Comment: I am using PS and Visual Studio Code
I can run: Get-EXOMailbox -Identity miguel@company -Properties DisplayName,EmailAddresses,Alias.....  I am using PS: Major:  5, Minor 1, Build 18362 Revision 1593

Comment: In a new window, try `Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement; Connect-ExchangeOnline;Get-EXOMailbox YourEmail@domain|Get-MailboxFolderStatistics`

Comment: ***FIXED***I am sorry for any inconvenience.  It looks like it was a permission issue.

Comment: @Miguel could you elaborate what you as an answer? i ran into this exact same issue, i would be interested in the solution